# QUERY SQL - Separar String

Tags: sql-server, sql, tsql, querystring

Estoy trabajando con unas consultas y me ha surgido la necesidad de tener que quedarme con solo una parte de un campo, es decir, tengo un campo que tiene una extensión final parecido a esto `13123243534.Consumo` y a la vez otros valores en ese mismo campo pero de longitud distinta, he intentado usar un `SUBSTRING` pero tengo que especificar donde empieza a recortar pero al tener longitud distinta no me sirve.

No sé si alguien sabe alguna manera de poder recordar desde que se encuentre el punto `.Consumo` hasta el final pero pudiendo recortar solo `Consumo` sin el punto.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar otros ejemplos para que sea más claro el patrón de lo que quieres eliminar?

Answer (score 4):

Prueba de usar las funciones de T-SQL `CHARINDEX` y `LEFT` / `RIGHT`:

[Página de ayuda](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

`CHARINDEX` busca la posición del carácter que deseas buscar.

`LEFT` y `RIGHT` hacen un substring hacia la dirección de la instrucción.

El ejemplo que te pondría para solucionar tu problema seria el sigguiente:

```
SELECT RIGHT('13123243534.Consumo', LEN('13123243534.Consumo') - CHARINDEX('.','13123243534.Consumo'))

//Recortamos por la derecha el largo del texto menos el índice de la posición del 
  punto, de esta manera obtienes el largo de la palabra colocada a la derecha
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la función [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) para saber la posición del '.' y hacer el substring desde ahí.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(campo,CHARINDEX('.', campo)+1,100) as camp FROM tabla
```